# perl populating arrays with filenames from user defined directory?

Tags: arrays, perl, glob, populate

I'm trying to populate two arrays with filenames from a user defined directory. The code I have so far works if the files are in the same directory where I'm running the program. The ultimate goal of this code is to convert a file from one format to another using a script, and exporting the newly converted files into a user defined directory.

```
# Get export directory
my $export_dir = $ARGV[0]."\\";

print "Export Directory: \"$export_dir\"\n\n" if DEBUG;

# Get current working directory
my $cwd_dir =  getcwd;

# Replace slashes with back-slashes for Windows compatibility
$cwd_dir =~ s/\//\\/g;

print "Current Working Directory: \"$cwd_dir\"\n\n" if DEBUG;


# Get list of ZIP files in directory
my @zip_files = glob "*.zip";
```

This code works when the zip files are in the current working directory. How do I get it to work where the zip files are in a user defined directory? (In this case a subfolder, but should be wherever the user defines the export directory).

Comment: You do not need to replace slashes `/` with backslashes `\ ` for your script to be Windows compatible: Windows understands slashes in paths. Try it and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply pre-pend the directory name to a glob spec:

```
my @zip_files = glob "$export_dir\\*.zip";
```

P.S. Ideally, you should use `File::Spec` CPAN module to construct file paths in OS-independent way, instead of hard-coding `"\\"` for Windows and `"/"` for Unix.

Comment: You need to be careful if paths that contain spaces, such as `Documents and settings`, are used, as they will not work with glob.

Comment: @TLP - yes, `File::Find` would be a more solid solution

Comment: Thanks guys, this seems to have worked. Only thing now is it's causing more problems later on. When checking if a file exists, do you know how to specifiy the directory aswell? I'm using if (-e $zip_file) but that only checks the current directory and not the user specified one.

Comment: Also, thanks for pointing out that directories can't have spaces with this method. I was confused for a while because it wasn't working. I'll look into {Find::Find} and see if I can find another way.

Comment: @odoc Why do you feel the need to check if the file exists? How could it not exist if you've just created a list of the files? If you feel that the file system could be altered while the script is running, you should probably look into an iterative solution such as `File::Find`, or `while (readdir $dh)`.

Comment: I need to check for the script that I'm running. Thanks, I figured it out: if (-e "$export_dir/$zip_file") seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You apparently want

```
my @zip_files = do { eval { chdir $export_dir } or die $!; my @x = glob "*.zip"; chdir $cwd_dir; @x };
```

Or, for a little bit less overkill (returns empty list if `$export_dir` is not a valid dir,

```
my @zip_files = eval { chdir $export_dir or die; my @x = glob "*.zip"; chdir $cwd_dir; @x };
```

Comment: It'not (IMHO) as overkill as having to pull `File::Spec` (which, I admit, is a solid solution). :D

Comment: I am referring to the fact that you can simply do `glob "$export_dir/*.zip"`.

Comment: But you said that paths with spaces may or may not work with glob. What I did was exactly to prevent that.

Comment: Yes, I was hoping you would not notice that. :) What you are doing here is using a very heavy arsenal to solve a problem for which there are more appropriate tools. In fact, you don't need `do` or `eval` here at all.